# How to deploy java project on github to Azure

Tags: java, azure, web, web-applications

So I made a simple java project with Spark and was trying to deploy it to Azure, but although it complies and says deploy successfully, it won't show any content. I used both the web+mobile deployment and the java jetty deployment, but none worked. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

The link to the github project is https://github.com/tonymuu/mini-twitter-clone

And the link to the website is minitwitter.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some documents and vedios to help you deploying Java web project into Azure from GitHub.

- Vedio: Deploying to Web Sites with GitHub using Kudu - with David Ebbo https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/deploying-to-azure-from-github/
- Document: Deploying from github https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-github

But for your issue, I checked your Java project on GitHub, and I found the repository only contains Java source code, not be a Java web application archive directory what contains the directories `WEB-INF`& `META-INFO`, and Java classes files in the path `WEB-INF/classes` and other web files, as the picture below:

[image]

Deploying Java web application on Azure WebApps is similar to deploying it into Tomcat or Jetty. You should deploy it into the directory `webapps`. on Azure WebApps, the `webapps` is at the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. You can find it thru the Debug console of  `Kudu` Tool at the url `https://<azure_webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

When you are deploying project from GitHub, the Azure will clone the files & directories of a branch of project repository from GitHub to the path `wwwroot` on Azure.

So the simple way to deploy from Github is push the `webapps/<java_app_name>` directory contains the files & directories of your Java web application archive into GitHub repository. Azure will help you pulling and deloping them.

Then you can browse the url `https://<azure_webapp_name>.azurewebsites.net/<java_app_name>/`.

If you create a Java web project by using Eclipse, the directory `WebContent` will be contained in the project. You just need to copy the content of `WebContent` into `webapps/<java_app_name>` dir and push `webapps` into GitHub repo.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for! I'm quite a newbie on web applications so this really cleared my vision :)