# Deploy java Tomcat application (war) on MS Azure

Tags: java, maven, azure, tomcat, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy my java project on MS Azure. Locally it works fine, also I successfully deployed it on AWS and Heroku.

My steps:

1) Upload code to github repository

2) Create WebApp on Azure

3) Configure settings:
 [image: app settings]

4) Go to deployment options & choose github

5) Select repository & press save

6) Wait for deployment

[image: deployment]

7) Open project url

But after all this steps I get "empty project pahe":
[image: web page]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `war` file was deployed to an incorrect path, which be caused by your github repository structure. Please refer to my answer for a similar SO thread [How to deploy java project on github to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439173/how-to-deploy-java-project-on-github-to-azure/33471708#33471708), and check your github repository structure whether the `war` file is under the path `<your-github-repository>/wwwroot/webapps`, then try to deployment via Github again.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.