# Pytest should not go to production Azure platform

Tags: python, azure, github, flask, pytest

I am writing a python flask web app and deployed into Azure successfully by following some basic tutorial. But the problem is all my pytests also go to cloud during deployment since I give github account, it directly pulls my code from my branch and deploys.

Can someone help me understand how the python project structure should be such that when I deploy to production in Azure all my pytest will not be deployed. Please see my current project structure.

```
my_app
--app
  |
  |---Module A
  |---Module B
  |---Module C
  |---Templates
  |---Tests
  |---my_app.py
  |---forms.py
  |---routes.py
  |---requirements.txt
```

Comment: That really depends on how you deploy to azure, can you edit your question to add this information ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simliar related SO thread for Java [How to deploy java project on github to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439173/how-to-deploy-java-project-on-github-to-azure/33471708#33471708), please refer to it carefully.

If you want to deploy a web app from GitHub to Azure WebApp via `Deployment Center`, as the figure below,

[image]

the `Deployment Center` will pull all content of the root of your GitHub repo into Azure WebApp.

So please do not push your `Tests` directory or other files what you not want for deployment.